# Best way to build a complex string

Tags: php

I have the need to put together a somewhat complex URL, here is what I have put together so far:

```
public static string $comparisonData = 'foo';

public function buildUrl(string $paramTwo, ?string $paramThree, ?string $paramFour, boolean $conditionalOne, string $conditionalTwo)
{
    $url = 'www.base_url.com?paramOne=';

    if ($conditionalOne) {
        $firstParam = $conditionalTwo == self::comparisonData ? 15233 : 1235662;
    } else {
        $firstParam = $conditionalTwo == self::comparisonData ? 123562212 : 2321;
    }

    $params = "&paramTwo=$paramTwo";
    if (!empty($paramThree)) {
        $params .= "&paramThree=$paramThree";
    }
    if (!empty($paramFour)) {
        $params .= "&paramFour=$paramFour";
    }

    return $url . $firstParam . $params;
}
```

The function works without issue and it won't be called regularly so doesn't need to be performant. I am curious to see how others would approach the task.

How would you go about constructing a URL with some optional data, and some conditional data?

Comment: If your code works and you just want someone to look it over, you should post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Personally, I would build an array of the parameters I wanted to use and use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in PHP function called [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) that could make your code a bit more readable.

Personally, I'd build up an array first of your required parameters, and then just send `buildUrl` an array of your parameters, instead of having `buildUrl` attempt to process it all for you, or you could move that logic to another function.

In your example, you've also got `string $conditionalOne`, which I'm assuming is supposed to be a `boolean`. This code could be changed again so that `processUrl` doesn't take the `$conditionalXXX` variables, and the condition is processed within the function instead, but I'm not sure what your use-case is so I'm attempting to keep the code familiar to yours.

Here's an example:

```php
public static string $comparisonData = 'foo';

public function processUrl($conditionalOne, $conditionalTwo, ?array $extraParams): string {
  // Build up Parameter One
  $paramOne = ($conditionalOne
                ? ($conditionalTwo == self::$comparisonData ? 15233 : 1235662)
                : ($conditionalTwo == self::$comparisonData ? 123562212 : 2321)
              );

  // The other parameters are quite simple
  // Using ?? here to fallback to an empty array for merge, if $extraParams is NULL
  $params = ['paramOne' => $paramOne] + ($extraParams ?? []);
  return $this->buildUrl($params);
}

private function buildUrl(array $params): string {
  $baseUrl = 'https://www.example.com/?';
  return $baseUrl . http_build_query($params);
}
```

Usage:

```php
$className->processUrl(TRUE, FALSE, [
  'paramTwo' => 'foo',
  'paramThree' => 'bar',
  'paramFour' => NULL, // http_build_query strips NULL key/values
]);

// Output:
https://www.example.com/?paramOne=1235662&paramTwo=foo&paramThree=bar
```

Comment: You're right, `$conditionalOne` should have been a boolean. I've corrected that in the code sample. Liking the solution.

Comment: Is there anything I could do to improve this answer for you to mark this as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to first set all of your variables so you have a clear view of those.

After that you could use a execution operator `

```
$url = `www.base_url.com?paramOne=$param&paramTwo=$paramTwo&paramThree=$paramThree&paramFour=$paramFour`;
```

After a comment from Nigel maybe this is a better option:

```
$params['param1'] = "value";
$params['param2'] = "value";
$params['param4'] = "value";

$url = 'www.base_url.com/';

$first = false;
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
   $url .= ($first) ? '?' : '&';
   $first = true;
                
   $url .= `$key=$value`;
}
```

Comment: What if some of the parameters are not used?